# Table Formatting in LaTex

Tags: tables, xetex, multirow

I am trying to create a table having the following outlook.

Any ideas why in the 1st column in the 2nd and 3rd merged rows are not aligned vertically in the middle like the 3rd row???

The same question goes for 3rd and 5th column in the 4th row, the text again is not aligned in the middle???

I am not sure if it matters that I am compiling with XeLaTex (and not e.g. with pdfLaTex).

Many thanks  !!!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{graphicx} 


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Two\\ Lines\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{Line} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Two\\ Lines\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Two\\ Lines\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Two\\ Lines\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Three\\ -\\ Lines\end{tabular}} &
  P1 &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that I would wish\\ to span in two Lines\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that\\ I would\\ wish to span\\ in four Lines\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that\\ I would \\ wish to span\\ in four Lines\end{tabular} \\ \cline{2-5} 
 &
  P2 &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that I would wish\\ to span in two Lines\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that\\ I would\\ wish to span\\ in four Lines\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that\\ I would\\ wish to span\\ in four Lines\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Three\\ -\\ Lines\end{tabular}} &
  A1 &
  \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text common\\ to all rows\\ Vertically Centered\\ in the Middle\end{tabular}} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that I would wish\\ to span in two Lines\end{tabular} &
  \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text common\\ to all rows\\ Vertically Centered\\ in the Middle\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A2 &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that I would wish\\ to span in two Lines\end{tabular} &
   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A3 &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that I would wish\\ to span in two Lines\end{tabular} &
   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A4 &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that I would wish\\ to span in two Lines\end{tabular} &
   \\ \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Three\\ -\\ Lines\end{tabular}} &
  A5 &
  \multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text common\\ to all rows\\ Vertically Centered\\ in the Middle\end{tabular}} &
  One Line Text &
  \multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text common\\ to all rows\\ Vertically Centered\\ in the Middle\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A6 &
   &
  One Line Text &
   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A7 &
   &
  One Line Text &
   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A8 &
   &
  One Line Text &
   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A9 &
   &
  One Line Text &
   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A10 &
   &
  One Line Text &
   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{TEST}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always provide a MWE for people to be able to compile it

Comment: Did you try booktabs?

Comment: totally correct @SergeyBelyaev. I just approved an edit and I already made some improvement.

Comment: I tried your example, and it does what you want if you set [b] option right after \multirow. I know this doesn't explain why tables behave in the way they do.

Comment: Honestly, if I knew what your cell content is, I would try to help you with booktabs layout of your table (because its feasibility strongly depends on the context). I do know this package a) works, b) provides better (=nicer looking) tables. Sometoimes it is easier to redo something, than to understand why the previous version doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more precise regarding the contents of your actual table? Do you really wish to manually split the text into multiple rows?

Comment: Hi. I would really would not like to split the lines manually. This is why I used the \resizebox option that resized the text proportionally to my margin constraints (or maybe it was left from previous tries). If I knew better before your comments, I would very much like to write simpler code like the one @Zarko provided. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Don't use `\resizebox`, with it you loose control on the font size. Fonts can become to small that can be read.
- The table generated by your MWE is (without use of `\resizebox`) wider than is text width.  To remedy this you can select one of the following possibilities:

  - make `\textwidth` wider, for example with use of the `\geometry` package
  - reduce font and `\tabcol`  size
  - define width of table in advance and use columns' type which enable automatically break text in more lines (if necessary). For example `tabularxy` table environment is promising.
- with use of `\thead` instruction from the `makecell` package, is possible to write shorter and more clean code for columns' headers
- defining column widths is possible to use new feature of the `multirow` package:

  - with option `=` multirow cell overtake defined width of a column.
  - with `\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}` are texts in `multirow` cells horizontal centered

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]   % <---
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells
\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering} % <-----
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |p{3em}|c| *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|} }
    \hline
\thead{Two\\ Lines} 
    &   \thead{Line} 
        &   \thead{Two\\ Lines} 
            &   \thead{Two\\ Lines} 
                &   \thead{Two\\ Lines} \\ 
    \hline
\multirow{7}{=}{Three\\ -\\ Lines} 
    &   P1 
        &   Text that I would wish to span in two Lines
            &   Text that I would wish to span in four Lines
                &   Text that I would wish to span in four Lines
                                        \\ 
    \cline{2-5}
    &   P2 
        &   Text that I would wish to span in two Lines
            &   Text that I would wish to span in four Lines
                &   Text that I would wish to span in four Lines
                                        \\ 
    \hline
\multirow{13}{=}{Three\\ -\\ Lines} 
    &   A1 
        &   \multirow{13}{=}{Text common to all rows Vertically Centered in the Middle}
            &   Text that I would wish to span in two Lines
                &   \multirow{13}{=}{Text common to all rows Vertically Centered in the Middle}                 \\ 
    \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
    &   A2 
        &   &   Text that I would wish to span in two Lines
                &                       \\ 
    \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
    &   A3 
        &   &   Text that I would wish to span in two Lines
                &                       \\ 
    \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
    &   A4 
        &   &   Text that I would wish to span in two Lines
                &                       \\ 
    \hline
\multirow{8}{=}{Three\\ -\\ Lines} 
    &   A5 
        &   \multirow{8}{=}{Text common\\ to all rows\\ Vertically Centered\\ in the Middle} 
            &   One Line Text 
                &   \multirow{8}{=}{Text common\\ to all rows\\ Vertically Centered\\ in the Middle}             \\ 
    \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
    &   A6 
        &   &   One Line Text   &       \\ 
    \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
    &   A7
        &   &   One Line Text   &       \\
    \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
    &   A8
        &   &   One Line Text   &       \\
    \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
    &   A9
        &   &   One Line Text   &       \\
    \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
    &   A10
        &   &   One Line Text   &       \\
   \hline
\end{tabularx}%
%}
\caption{TEST}
\label{tab:my-table}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: Hi and many thanks for your solution. I will definitely keep your solution in mind since it is much simpler and structured code. However, if only the text was vertically aligned in the middle and horizontally aligned in the center.

Comment: @V.Nikolaidis, ups, I didn't upload the last vewrsion of my answer. In code is mising code line `\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}`. Corrected now.

Comment: @V.Nikolaidis, any news? Does answer now fulfill your expectation? Now is time that you decided, which of obtained answer is the best for you needs and accept them (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer). SO far as I see you not accept any of answers received on your questions :-(

Comment: I thought by answering to all and by upvoting answers that I liked was they way to go. I am still not entirely familiar with the whole system ;-). I liked and tried all answers, however as I wrote again in an earlier message, I used a combination of @Sveinung code along with my tries to finish what I had started. However, I upvoted your code since it produces the same result and the code is much clearer and simpler. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have misunderstood the use of [multirow](https://ctan.org/pkg/multirow). You have to span the number of "normal" rows because [multirow](https://ctan.org/pkg/multirow) does not know the height of the spanning box, see page 6 in the manual and the example given there:

> 1. The middle column is the \multirow. You would expect it to be vertically
>      centered, but it isn’t. This is because \multirow doesn’t know the height
>      of the box. The only estimate \multirow can make about the height is the
>      number of rows  the normal height of a row. It tries to center the text in
>      that space, but that space is too low in this example. Therefore the text is
>      at the top of the box. If you want it to be centered, you have to supply a
>      hvmovei argument to shift it down.

Just increase the number of spanned rows, as indicated below, or fine tune utilising the optional argument `[vmode=]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{graphicx} 


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Two\\ Lines\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{Line} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Two\\ Lines\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Two\\ Lines\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Two\\ Lines\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Three\\ -\\ Lines\end{tabular}} &
  P1 &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that I would wish\\ to span in two Lines\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that\\ I would\\ wish to span\\ in four Lines\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that\\ I would \\ wish to span\\ in four Lines\end{tabular} \\ \cline{2-5} 
 &
  P2 &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that I would wish\\ to span in two Lines\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that\\ I would\\ wish to span\\ in four Lines\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that\\ I would\\ wish to span\\ in four Lines\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Three\\ -\\ Lines\end{tabular}} &
  A1 &
  \multirow{7}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text common\\ to all rows\\ Vertically Centered\\ in the Middle\end{tabular}} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that I would wish\\ to span in two Lines\end{tabular} &
  \multirow{7}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text common\\ to all rows\\ Vertically Centered\\ in the Middle\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A2 &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that I would wish\\ to span in two Lines\end{tabular} &
   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A3 &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that I would wish\\ to span in two Lines\end{tabular} &
   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A4 &
   &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text that I would wish\\ to span in two Lines\end{tabular} &
   \\ \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Three\\ -\\ Lines\end{tabular}} &
  A5 &
  \multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text common\\ to all rows\\ Vertically Centered\\ in the Middle\end{tabular}} &
  One Line Text &
  \multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Text common\\ to all rows\\ Vertically Centered\\ in the Middle\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A6 &
   &
  One Line Text &
   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A7 &
   &
  One Line Text &
   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A8 &
   &
  One Line Text &
   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A9 &
   &
  One Line Text &
   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 &
  A10 &
   &
  One Line Text &
   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%

\caption{TEST}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Sveinung. Thank you for your time spent in my problem. I did combine your solution with some of my own tries. So in the 2,3 &4th `\multirow{7}{*}` I used the [b] option ( `\multirow[b]{4}{*}` ) proposed by @Sergey and it somehow worked ;-)

Comment: @V.Nikolaidis The b-option works by coincident, this will depend on the number of of spanned lines. Try to increase or decrease the number of lines, and see the effect. According to the manual, you should use [vmode=] to adjust the vertical alignment.